# How to copy and paste multiple email addresses into Yahoo Mail

Tags: yahoo-mail

For the [new Yahoo Mail (June 2017 version)](https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/27/15880222/yahoo-mail-redesign-pro-ui-update), I cannot figure out a way to copy and paste multiple email addresses when composing a new email. I tried delimiting with semicolons, commas, and spaces, but it only retains the first and last email in the "To" field. For example:

```
user1@yahoo.com; user2@yahoo.com; user3@yahoo.com

user1@yahoo.com, user2@yahoo.com, user3@yahoo.com

user1@yahoo.com user2@yahoo.com user3@yahoo.com
```

Will result in this (only the first and last emails are retained):

[image]

This used to work with the previous "Classic Yahoo Mail" (prior to June 2017 version).

Comment: @pnuts I was trying it for about 8 emails. I also tried separation by space, same result.